# how to access patch version in Salesforce managed package post install script

Tags: apex, managed-package, metadata-api

We have been trying to access the salesforce patch version from post install script part of our managed package. System.requestVersion().patch() always returns null.

It's mentioned in the SF documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_version.htm) as well and we have cross verified the same with SF support that it always returns null.

Does anyone knows if there is any other way we could access the patch version in post install script?